# JSON - No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: c#, .net, json, visual-studio, json.net

I’m trying to debug a problem.

I have been given a url to which I  can send JSON commands via HTTP POST.  If I stick the URL into Chrome I get a properly formatted response – all good.

If I put the same url into internet explorer (IE 11) I get a ‘The website is unable to display the webpage  -This error (HTTP 501 Not Implemented or HTTP 505 Version Not Supported) means that the website you are visiting doesn’t currently have the ability to display the webpage, or support the HTTP version used to request the page.’ – Not sure whats going here

I ultimately need to send a command via a web service, to this end I have created a very simple app in visual studio.

I use this code, but then I get the error:

```
    var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://URL.....");
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new
            {
                operation = "****",
                username = "****",
                password = "****"
            });

            streamWriter.Write(json);
        }

        var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        }
```

{"No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 1.1.1.1:443"}
There is a problem, but being new to this I have no idea where to start looking.

Any pointers appreciated.

Comment: Make sure your url:port is correct and can be reached from your machine (that means, server should be able to receive request through its opened port (check firewall), and client should be able to access the server (connectivity and firewall))

Comment: If you stick the url into chrome and get a response that is a GET, not POST.

Comment: so there is nothing wrong with the code then?

Comment: ok, so maybe I've missed something obvious.  the first attempt was done in web app - that failed.  Just tried the same code in windows app and it works fine?